# "becoming hopeful of "

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encountered this sentence and felt quite bemused:

["After many years of feeling stymied by his senior managers, Clark was becoming hopeful of advancement."](https://press.uchicago.edu/Misc/Chicago/467597.html)

Why many years under such feeling makes a person becoming hopeful of advancing instead of devastating? Most dictionary defines hopeful as optimistic, which confounded my problems even more. Could anyone please help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's a literary way to build tension/expectation by the writer.

First: "After many years of feeling stymied by his senior managers": This sets an expectation for him feeling down, and unable to progress.

Second: "Clark was becomming hopeful of advancement" This is a dichotomy to the former statement, as it is the opposite of what we would expect.

Third: In the following paragraf is then stated several reasons for why he were hopeful, in spite of the situation. This creates a sense of relieve for the reader, as they now has an answer to the prior mismatch between being stymied and being hopeful.

Comment: Lenny - Note the last sentence of Paragraph 2 - "Here, finally, might be an opportunity to make his mark" (by being invited to give a radio talk).